# apple mach-o linker (id) error after adding admob (Unity)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

i made a demo game in unity and i wanted to add admob to it to test how it looks on the iPhone, so i followed this guide from google : https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start . Without the admob, the project worked fine and it builds on iOS, but after adding admob i first run into this error : 'GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h' file not found , so then i added GoogleMobileAds.framework to xCode project , but once i build the project i got this error :
[image]

any help please, i spent hours searching :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot, it seems like you're missing: 
`GLKit.framework CoreTelephony.framework CoreMedia.framework CoreVideo.framework MessageUI.framework CFNetwork.framework MobileCoreServices.framework StoreKit.framework AdSupport.framework Security.framework`.

Comment: is the  `_objc_class_$_GLKView` error still present?

Comment: no, that error is gone, but i still have the other errors that contain 'GoogleMobileAds'

Comment: after adding all the frameworks you mentioned,a lot of error are gone but am still left with these : https://imgur.com/a/tCS1G

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160308/discussion-between-shaman-and-alex).