# Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error Admob Unity Xcode

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

Hi guys i try to build my game from unity with admob. before i import admob to my project i can build and test it on my devices from xcode.. but after i use admob and export the project as xcode project and try to build the project. i got error like [this the error you can click to see the screenshot of my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmetT.png)

before i get that error i have include the admob framework to my xcode project.. but after i import admob framework to my framework folder i get some error like in the screenshot. first, im trying to build using unity 2017.3.0p4 and the latest admob sdk but i got thats error, i try to make some new project with other unity version using unity 5.6.1p4 and error is still the same.. i have ask this question at unity forum but there's nothing can help me.. i hope if somebody here have the same problem and have to fixed or solved it please share some tips for me. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It's already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598406/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error-after-adding-admob-unity/47598859#47598859). In short, you are just missing some frameworks shown in that answer.